# Change Shipping Address Form to Billing Address Form on Guests Checkout Magento2 2.3

Tags: magento2, checkout, address

my client wants that the shop guests should first fill in the billing address instead of the shipping address on the checkout page.

How can I change the shipping address form with the billing address form? Is there any Extensions?

Thanks in Advance